# 特定のクラスをもつ子要素の数を取得したい

Tags: javascript, html

例えば

```
<div id="oya">
  <div class="a">aaa</div>
  <div class="a">aaa</div>
  <div class="b">bbb</div>
  <div class="a">aaa</div>
</div>
```

こういうhtmlがあるとき、oyaがいくつaクラスを持つ子要素を持っているか、もしくはいくつ持っているかを取得したいです。
`children[0].className`というように一度試してみたのですが、`'className' of undefined`が出てできませんでした...。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` で簡単に取得できます。

```
document.querySelectorAll('#oya > .a').length
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ちなみにoyaがidではなくクラスで複数ある場合でも同様にできますか？

Comment: 「すべてのoyaのclass="a"の子供の総計」でしたら、同様に querySelectorAll() 一回、「それぞれのoyaのclass="a"の子供の数」でしたら、querySelectorAll() を2段階に分けることで可能です。